# Is it possible to reconstruct the base64 file from indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I had indexed the attachment(base64 file) in elasticsearch. 
So i want to know whether it is possible to recreate the attachment from indexes stored in elasticsearch.
 If yes then how i can reconstruct it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is base64 Decoders in pretty much every programming programming languages. If you have a problem decoding the base64, add more details to your question.

Comment: i dont want to decode base64 file. i want to reconstruct file from indexes stored by elasticsearch

Comment: Then can you be more precise. What do you mean by reconstruct ? I thought you meant recover the content of the file in order to have the original data.

Comment: elasticsearch create indices of input attachment and from that indices I want to create original file.For eg :- i had indexed the text file (by converting it into base64) . Now i had deleted that text as well as base64 file. Now i am left with indices stored by elasticsearch. so from those indices i want to construct original file

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to recover the data of an indexed file in Elasticsearch. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the file's contents, then sure.  Simply search for the appropriate documents, and retrieve the stored contents.

If you did not store it, then no.  Even if you are willing to attempt to manually reconstruct it from the inverted index, the process would necessarily be lossy.

ElasticSearch [Attachment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type/)'s documentation provides an example on setting this.

Comment: i had recovered file in base 64 format.For that command is:- curl -XGET "localhost:9200/test/attachment/[unique_id]